# Data gotten from my REST api does not display

Tags: react-native, rest, react-native-flatlist

Something i want to ask. Querying My REST api, i get the following information from the REST api

```
  "error": false,   "data": [

      "id": 4,
      "date": "2022-12-12",
      "email": "jonathan_kross@yopmail.com",
      "narration": "Shoppings",
      "credit": 0,
      "debit": 450000,
      "created_at": "2022-12-13T06:06:03.581Z"


      "id": 5,
      "date": "2022-12-12",
      "email": "jonathan_kross@yopmail.com",
      "narration": "Export Trade LLC",
      "credit": 700000,
      "debit": 0,
      "created_at": "2022-12-13T06:07:17.571Z"


  "message": "user transaction list" }
```

So i want to display the date, narration, say credit on the flat list
My flat list is looking thus

```
  `<View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 35}}>
    {isLoading ? (
      <ActivityIndicator />
    ) : (
      <FlatList
        style={{fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium', alignSelf: 'center'}}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
        data={transaction_details}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <View style={{flex: 2, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text style={styles.PayeeName}>
              {item.narration}
              {'   '}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.date_ofTransaction}>{item.date}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.amountValue}>{item.credit}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      />
    )}
  </View>`
```

I just do not get anything as a value and the project is empty, No idea why. I would be needing assistance here.

It is supposed to show the data on the Flatlist, but the flat list is very empty , i do not know why

**Edit.**

```
The full source code is looking like this :

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Button,
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {Header, Avatar, Icon, Card} from '@rneui/themed';
import {FlatList, ScrollView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Tab} from '@rneui/base';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const HomePage = () => {
  const [transaction_details, setTransaction_details] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const Item = ({title}) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: 350,
          backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  showdata = async () => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    alert(token);
  };

  getTransactionsList = async () => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    let email = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');

    fetch('https://mg2g2.herokuapp.com/api/fetch-transaction/' + email, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': +token,
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setTransaction_details(responseJson);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //showdata();
    this.getTransactionsList();
  });

  /*useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/people/people.php', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setTransaction_details(responseJson);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
  */

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Header
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
        }}
        leftComponent={
          <Avatar
            small
            rounded
            source={{
              uri: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSiRne6FGeaSVKarmINpum5kCuJ-pwRiA9ZT6D4_TTnUVACpNbzwJKBMNdiicFDChdFuYA&usqp=CAU',
            }}
            onPress={() => console.log('Left Clicked!')}
            activeOpacity={0.7}
          />
        }
        rightComponent={
          <Icon
            name={'mail-outline'}
            color={'#00BB23'}
            size={32}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Accounts')}
          />
        }></Header>

      <ImageBackground
        source={{
          uri: 'asset:/logo/bg.JPG',
        }}
        imageStyle={{borderRadius: 6}}
        style={{
          top: 15,
          paddingTop: 95,
          alignSelf: 'center',
          width: 328,
          height: 145,
          borderadius: 9,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignSelf: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.accText}>Wallet Balance</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}> 250,000 </Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
      <View>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            paddingTop: 55,
            fontSize: 15,
            left: 18,
            color: 'gray',
          }}>
          Recent Transactions
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 35}}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            style={{fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium', alignSelf: 'center'}}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            data={transaction_details}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
              console.log(item);
              return (
                <View style={{flex: 2, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Text style={styles.PayeeName}>
                    {item.narration}
                    {'   '}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.date_ofTransaction}>{item.date}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.amountValue}>{item.credit}</Text>
                </View>
              );
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  date_ofTransaction: {
    marginTop: 20,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    left: -75,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Light',
    fontSize: 9,
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  text: {
    top: -85,
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold',
  },
  mainContainer: {
    paddingTop: 90,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  accText: {
    top: -85,
    paddingTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  PayeeName: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    left: 23,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    size: 800,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  amountValue: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    top: -30,
    right: -25,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium',
    size: 800,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

**Edit**

@sadia Chaundary

```
<View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 35}}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            style={{fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium', alignSelf: 'center'}}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            data={transaction_details}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
              //console.log(item);
              return (
                <View style={{flex: 2, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <Text style={styles.PayeeName}>
                    {item.narration}
                    {'   '}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.date_ofTransaction}>{item.date}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.amountValue}>{item.credit}</Text>
                </View>
              );
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          />
        )}
      </View>
```

That is what the flatlist looks like, but however its scattered. Looks like this

[image: Screenshot-1671454891.png]

What could possibly be wrong? like why is it scattered

Comment: can you please change this and let me know what happens : -> setTransaction_details(responseJson.data);

Comment: @AnkitVora, nothing. Flatlist is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
      ...
      .then(response => response.json()) 
      .then(responseJson => {
        setTransaction_details(responseJson); //---> you need to change this into setTransaction_details(responseJson.data); 
        setLoading(false);
      });
      ...
```

Comment: Does not show data on Flatlist

Comment: Can you see the response in console.log?

Comment: Also, the style of flatlist, style={{fontFamily: 'Poppins-Medium', alignSelf: 'center'}}, will not work.

Comment: Can you give flatlist style, flex: 1? and contentContainerStyle, flexGrow:1? 
Try to give height or something. If the console statement is working fine then, you style needs to be changed.

Comment: i managed to do some serious debugging and it works , but its very scattered on my Flat list. Need to align to be ok visually. Pls see edits.

Comment: Remove "alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    top: -30," from your amountValue styles.

Comment: that i did , still not aligning properly @sadia

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@sadiac/surprised-stroopwafels